# Unable to Subscribe Again after manually deleting user on RevenueCat on iOS (Sandbox React Native)

Tags: ios, react-native, subscription, revenuecat

I am using React Native. I successfully implemented purchase function and tested by using Sandbox. After I purchased on my test phone, I went into the RevenueCat dashboard and saw the new anonymous user as expected. I deleted this user on the RevenueCat dashboard so that I can try purchasing again. However, when I press the button to subscribe, I keep getting a pop up that reads,

"You're currently subscribed to this. Your subscription to Annual $2.99 renews on May 24, 2022 for $2.99. To review subscription options or cancel subscription, tap Manage. [Environment: Sandbox]"

When I press 'Manage' on the alert box, it just says, 'Cannot Connect, Retry.'

Could you help me debug this so that this alert stops showing so that I can test the purchase functionality again? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The subscription is still associated with the underlying sandbox account with Apple. You need to set up a new sandbox account in App Store Connect as well as deleting from RevenueCat to start completely fresh.

Deleting a customer out of RevenueCat only removes it from the RevenueCat server - it doesn't delete or revoke the subscription with Apple as they don't allow developers do perform this functionality.